# How is roadway geometry stored/represented in OSM files?

Tags: openstreetmap, graph

I am interested in solving some questions for which I would like to extract only roadway geometry from some OpenStreetMaps (OSM) files. (As an aside, I'll eventually represent the data as a adjacency matrix-style graph). These files contain quite a few types of tags, keys, attributes, etc., but I suspect most are irrelevant to the actual roadway geometry. My questions are:

1. What is the structure of street geometry data within an OSM file? I suspect that roadways between intersections (nodes) are stored as polylines where each node and point on the polyline has a GPS coordinate and associated metadata. However, I have yet to confirm this.
2. What unique signifiers are used to represent this data within a .osm file? I'd like enough information that I could write a script to parse the relevant information from an osm file, as right now I cannot make sense of the many attributes in the data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question.  Bulleted question lists are likely to generate closure votes.  Please [Edit] your question to focus on one question.

Comment: Roads are multlinestrings.  You'll need to either download shapefiles from something like http://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html or if you need to filter differently, download the osm file and extract the data you need with something like osmfilter - here's an example `..\osmfilter indiana.osm --keep="highway=motorway =motorway_link =trunk =trunk_link =primary =primary_link =secondary =secondary_link =tertiary =tertiary_link" --keep-tags="lanes=*" >in_roads_lanes.osm`